# Storing values in Array in ARM-Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I have a predefined array in ARM-Assembly like

```
Sample  DCD 0x003, 0x004, 0x005, 0x006
```

I just want to change indexes of Sample[0] and Sample[1]

And I wrote a ARM-Assembly code for swapping

```
LDR R0, =Sample
LDR R1, [R0]
LDR R2, [R0, #4]
MOV R3, R1
MOV R1, R2
MOV R2, R3
STR R1, [R0]
STR R2, [R0, #4]
```

And I fetching the data one by one into R4 like

```
MAIN
LDR R4, [R0], #4
B MAIN
```

It looks like so simple but array is not changing, it still same

How can I change the indexes?

Briefly my input is

```
Sample  DCD 0x003, 0x004, 0x005, 0x006
```

And I want the output like

```
Sample  DCD 0x004, 0x003, 0x005, 0x006
```

Comment: Is the array in a writeable section of memory? By the way, those three `MOV` instructions are unnecessary; you can just do `STR R2,[R0]`, `STR R1,[R0, #4]`.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the optimization, but I don't understand what is the writable section of memory. R0 starting at 0x000000D0

Comment: I mean something like `AREA DATA, READWRITE`

Answer (score 2):

Your array is not changing because you need to ADR the arrow before loading it. 
Your code is not doing anything because you don't load the memory address. This would work.

```
   ADR     R0, Sample
   LDR     R1, [R0]
   LDR     R2, [R0, #4]
   MOV     R3, R1
   MOV     R1, R2
   MOV     R2, R3
   STR     R1, [R0]
   STR     R2, [R0, #4]
```